# Can't Connect to SalesForce in C#

Tags: c#, api, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am following this tutorial http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

However, I am getting this error:

> LOGIN_MUST_USE_SECURITY_TOKEN: Invalid username, password, security
>   token; or user locked out. Are you at a new location? When accessing
>   Salesforce--either via a desktop client or the API--from outside of
>   your company’s trusted networks, you must add a security token to your
>   password to log in. To receive a new security token, log in to
>   salesforce.com at http://login.salesforce.com and click Setup | My
>   Personal Information | Reset Security Token.

This is my code in my Console App:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName;
            string password;
            userName = "me@myWebsite.com";
            password = "myPassword";

            SforceService SfdcBinding = null;
            LoginResult CurrentLoginResult = null;
            SfdcBinding = new SforceService();
            try
            {
                CurrentLoginResult = SfdcBinding.login(userName, password);
            }
            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
            {
                // This is likley to be caused by bad username or password
                SfdcBinding = null;
                throw (e);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // This is something else, probably comminication
                SfdcBinding = null;
                throw (e);
            }

        }
```

The error states I need a security token, but the documentation never seems to mention it and I'm not sure how to get one.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I am following the same tutorial. I have added the wsdl xml file as instructed and added the service reference.

Then in my code I have exactly as you have above but and added using BST.SFDC;But on the line SforceService SfdcBinding = null; I am getting the error "The type or namespace name 'SforceService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I believe you have to add a `using [WhateverNameYouGaveYourWSDLFile];` statement.  I can double check for you when I get in the office tomorrow; but I am fairly certain.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: im wondering if I have used the wrong wsdl file - im using the enterprise one? which one did you use?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Fairly certain I used the *Partner WSDL*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I had to do (which was not in the documentation) is go to here:

https://na15.salesforce.com/_ui/system/security/ResetApiTokenConfirm?retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DPersonalInfo&setupid=ResetApiToken

And, reset my token.  Then, append it to the end of my password like:

> If your password = "mypassword"
>
> And your security token = "XXXXXXXXXX"
>
> You must enter "mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX" in place of your password

Ref. http://docs.servicerocket.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=83099770

Answer (score 2):

With a SOAP API like this you need to authenticate to the service first by providing the username and password. Their response should return an authorization token that will be valid for a period of time. Then in your subsequent communications you pass this token to the API so that it knows who you are.

Get the authorization token:

```
SforceService SfdcBinding = null;
LoginResult CurrentLoginResult = null;
SfdcBinding = new SforceService();
try 
{
   CurrentLoginResult = SfdcBinding.login(userName, password);
}
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e) 
{
   // This is likely to be caused by bad username or password
   SfdcBinding = null;
   throw (e);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // This is something else, probably communication
   SfdcBinding = null;
   throw (e);
}
```

Setup the session:

```
//Change the binding to the new endpoint
SfdcBinding.Url = CurrentLoginResult.serverUrl;

//Create a new session header object and set the session id to that returned by the login
SfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
SfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = CurrentLoginResult.sessionId;
```

Perform your query:

```
QueryResult queryResult = null;
String SOQL = "select FirstName, LastName, Phone from Lead where email = 'john.smith@salesforce.com'";
queryResult = SfdcBinding.query(SOQL);
```

Comment: Thanks for increasing my understanding but how does this differ from what I am already doing?  The problem is, I am getting the error `LOGIN_MUST_USE_SECURITY_TOKEN`

Comment: Are you sure the username/password is correct? Does SalesForce.com have any API tools that would let you test the username/password for correctness?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I fixed it finally by resetting my security token and adding the token after my password.  This isn't in the documentation that I was reading; but thankfully I figured it out.